# Apply line spacing to matrix of math nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, tikz-node

I want to make a matrix of math nodes using Tikz. Some entries in the matrix are very long and I want to introduce line spacing to align them in the same row as the following inputs. However, when I try to do this the input completely dissapears from the compiled document.

Is there any way to do this or do I need to use normal nodes and force the math mode manually?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,trees,positioning,arrows.meta,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}



\tikzset{
    mystyle/.style={column sep=0.25em, row sep=0.1em, minimum size=1cm, text width=2cm, align=center, anchor=center},
}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {mystyle},%
             left delimiter  = {[},%
             right delimiter = {]}]
{%
{\Gamma \theta and more math mode \\ but this time on two lines \Kappa} & more input & 0 & 0 &  \ldots & 0 \\
Another line & more input & 0 & 0 &  \ldots & 0\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (T) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {mystyle},%
             left delimiter  = {[},%
             right delimiter = {]}] 
{% 
Test \\
Test 2 \\
};

\node [mystyle, right= 0.4cm of T] {= Answer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{I want to include linespacing in this tikz figure in the first column.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a `gathered` or `multlined` environment in the nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,trees,positioning,arrows.meta,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{
    mystyle/.style={column sep=0.25em, row sep=0.1em, minimum size=1cm, text width=2cm, align=center, anchor=center},
}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {mystyle},%
             left delimiter  = {[},%
             right delimiter = {]}]
{%
\begin{gathered}
  \Gamma \theta \\
  \epsilon\delta
 \end{gathered} & \begin{multlined} a \\ b \end{multlined} & 0 & 0 &  \ldots & 0 \\
Another line & more input & 0 & 0 &  \ldots & 0\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (T) [matrix of math nodes,%
             nodes = {mystyle},%
             left delimiter  = {[},%
             right delimiter = {]}] 
{% 
Test \\
Test 2 \\
};

\node [mystyle, right= 0.4cm of T] {= Answer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{I want to include linespacing in this tikz figure in the first column.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using the gathered environment indeed allows me to use multiple lines in one node. However the font size of the other nodes on the same vertical line decreases to accomodate this. Is this a common problem?

Comment: @Frits No idea why that would happen, it doesn't happen here.